# react-select async request method

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-select

I'm using `react-select async` and I found some issues where every `onkeyup` event react-select make a request to the server, comparing to jquery select2 it will cancel previouse request and only execute latest request with the latest keyword.

my question is "is this normal in react-select or theres some option to use to make it work like jquery select2"

at this time if I type like 100 characters or more then react-select will make 100 requests too,
there my pc will start screaming handling all those requests

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is in implementation, not controlled by the control itself. The `AsyncSelect`s `loadOptions` would expect a promise that resolves your `option`s. It does not control the request, only fires it. Without seeing your code, it's impossible to see what it is you are using to handle your async calls. With something like [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) you can handle this sort of functionality using a [cancelToken](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation), but `react-select` isn't going to manage this for you.